# How do I disable cors for requests from external servers in c3.js?

Tags: javascript, html, c3.js

I am making a web app, where the user adds a device, that has a server running on it that serves csv data from a built-in sensor. When I try to load the data from the server, I get the error ,

```
Access to fetch at 'http://10.0.1.132:42069/data.csv' from origin 'http://10.0.1.118:8887' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

But I do not know to set the request mode to no-cors. How do I set it to no-cors?